# ASIHTTPRequest and ASINetworkQueue and JSON Parsing

Tags: asihttprequest, sbjson

```
//
//  RootViewController.m
//  JsonPetser33
//
//  Created by ME on 9/26/11.
//  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "RootViewController.h"
//
#import "SBJson.h"
#import "ASIHTTPRequest.h"
#import "ASINetworkQueue.h"
//
@implementation RootViewController
//
@synthesize mNetworkQueue;
@synthesize mArrData;
//
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //adding right button
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                              initWithTitle:@"Load"
                                              style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone 
                                              target:self
                                              action:@selector(loadData)];
}

-(void) loadData{
    //Stop anything already in the queue before removing it
    [[self mNetworkQueue] cancelAllOperations];
    //Creating a new queue each time we use it means we don't have to worry about clearing delegates or resetting progress tracking
    [self setMNetworkQueue:[ASINetworkQueue queue]];
    [[self mNetworkQueue] setDelegate:self];
    [[self mNetworkQueue] setRequestDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestFinished:)];
    [[self mNetworkQueue] setRequestDidFailSelector:@selector(requestFailed:)];
    [[self mNetworkQueue] setQueueDidFinishSelector:@selector(queueFinished:)];

    //create url request using ASIHTTPRequest
    ASIHTTPRequest *request;
    request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL
                                              URLWithString:@"http://mikan-box.x10.bz/testing/json_test.php"]];
    [[self mNetworkQueue] addOperation:request];

    [[self mNetworkQueue] go];
}
//ASIHTTPRequest protocol?
- (void) requestFinished: (ASIHTTPRequest *)request{
    //You could release the queue here if you wanted
    if ([[self mNetworkQueue] requestsCount] == 0) {

        //Since this is a retained property, setting it to nil will release it
        //This is the safest way to handle releasing things - most of the time you only ever need to release in your accessors
        //And if you an Objective-C 2.0 property for the queue (as in this example) the accessor is generated for you
        [self setMNetworkQueue:nil];
    }
    //... Handle success
    //parsing the data
    SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [SBJsonParser new];
    NSDictionary *dicTemp = [jsonParser objectWithData:[request responseData]];//parse json
    mArrData = [dicTemp objectForKey:@"markers"];
//do something like loading data in table for now NSLog data
NSLog(@"markers: %@",mArrData);             //here the app freezes can't click button etc for a few seconds//
    NSLog(@"count %d",[mArrData count]);        // how can i enhance it?
    [jsonParser release];



    NSLog(@"Request finished");
}
- (void) requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{
    //You could release the queue here if you wanted
    if ([[self mNetworkQueue] requestsCount] == 0) {
        [self setMNetworkQueue:nil];
    }
    //... Handle failure
    NSLog(@"Request failed: %@",[[request error] localizedDescription]);
}

-(void) queueFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *) queue{
    //You could release the queue here if you wanted
    if ([[self mNetworkQueue] requestsCount] == 0) {
        [self setMNetworkQueue:nil];
    }
    NSLog(@"Queue finished");
}
//


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Relinquish ownership any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];

    // Relinquish ownership of anything that can be recreated in viewDidLoad or on demand.
    // For example: self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [mNetworkQueue reset];
    [mNetworkQueue release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

- im new to objective-c and to ios.. i use the ASIHTTPRequest because it already has a httphandler..
- the problem is when i do http request from the url given(its json) it freezes during parsing and displaying "NSLog(@"markers: %@",mArrData)".. is there a way i could improve this code?
- i would like to improve this code like doing it in another thread just like the ASINetworkQueue done for the url request
- i heard about gcd (Grand central dispatch) but dont know how or even if it is useful..
- thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried not using an ASINetworkQueue and just using a simple ASIHTTPRequest and using startAsynchronous? For example:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mikan-box.x10.bz/testing/json_test.php"];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

If you have multiple requests you can use `[request setTag:tag]` to differentiate them in `requestFinished:`.

Comment: yeah i did try using that where in inside my requestFinished: i do my parsing there

it still freezes during parsing and displaying data.. about a few seconds..

i heard about subclassing the ASIHTTPRequest and overide requestFinished and do my parsing there before i call [super requestFinished].. but how do i do that? do i need to work with delegates here?.. thanx for a fast reply though..

Comment: It looks like you'll need to use GCD to run your post-processing in a separate thread because if you're using an asynchronous request and its still blocking the UI then the problem lies in whatever you're doing while processing. Unfortunately I don't know enough about GCD to give you any help with that part, sorry!